# Make child element wider than parent

Tags: css

I have a wrapper width of 720px, in it are some paragraphs and images. I need the paragraphs to be at 720px width, but the images should be wider (900px) and should extend the wrapper width. How can I do this?

```
    <div class="wrapper">
        <p>...</p>
        <img>
        <p>...</p>
        <img>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

basically you don't have to do anything special. See the orange border which is set on the `.wrapper` element, That's 720px wide. The image just goes over it. As long as you haven't done anything else (which you didn't list in the question)...

```css
.wrapper {
    width: 720px;
    border: solid 5px orange;
}
```

```html
 <div class="wrapper">
        <p>...</p>
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/900/700">
        <p>...</p>
        <img>
    </div>
```

Comment: Well my website has several containers, and if I just use the above html, the images only have the width of the wrapper. I need them to extend equally on both sides.

Comment: @mark extend equally on both sides it's something you should write in the question. you can not just add more requirements somewhere in the comments. When you post your question it should be complete.

Answer (score -1):

```css
.wrapper{
  width:fit-content;
}
img{
  width:900px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
        <p>...</p>
        <img src="https://eoimages.gsfc.nasa.gov/images/imagerecords/146000/146220/lakebaikalring_oli_201692_th.jpg">
        <p>...</p>
        <img src="https://eoimages.gsfc.nasa.gov/images/imagerecords/146000/146220/lakebaikalring_oli_201692_th.jpg">
    </div>
```